# Simple code to calculate age based on given date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If user enters dob as 10/19/1980, user's age is calculated based on 'effective date' instead of current date. There is a rule to calculate this 'effective date'.

```
// The rule is that if:
// current date is Feb 25  2021 : then 'effective date' is Apr-1-2021
// current date is Feb 3 2021, then 'effective date' is Mar 1 2021

const [effectiveDate, setEffectiveDate] = useState(new Date());

function calculateAge(userSelectedYear, dob) {
  // dob is a string eg. 1980-10-19
  const today = new Date();
  const cutOffDate = new Date(today).getFullYear();
  const selectedYear = userSelectedYear;
  const defaultStartDate = new Date('2020-11-15');
  const newDob = new Date(dob);

  if (today.getFullYear() === selectedYear && cutOffDate > today) {
    if (today.getDate() <= 15) {
      // Current Date is on or before 15 of a month
      setEffectiveDate(new Date(selectedYear, today.getMonth() + 1, 1));
    } else {
      // Current date is after 15th of the month
      setEffectiveDate(new Date(selectedYear, today.getMonth() + 2, 1));
    }
  } else if (today.getFullYear() === selectedYear && cutOffDate <= today) {
    setEffectiveDate(new Date(selectedYear, 11, 31));
  } else {
    setEffectiveDate(new Date(selectedYear, defaultStartDate.getMonth(), 1));
  }
  const age = effectiveDate.getFullYear() - newDob.getFullYear();

  return age;
}
```

Is there a better way to right this code?

Comment: What `selectedYear` changes in the algorithm? And what is `defaultStartDate`? From what you explained, just with the `dob` and the current date, you could tell the user age.

Comment: @Alyson - dob should be calculated from effectiveDate, not current date. Added 'defaultStartDate'. In actual code, this date is selected from a date picker

Comment: What's the logic behind the calculateAge()? Return age with years, months rounded?

Comment: return age in years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```js
var stringexample = "1980-10-19";
var x = moment(stringexample, "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow(true);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText = x;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If not using current time, you can calculate the difference between two dates using [.diff()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).